# open camera from a local notification in iphone

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am working on an application in which I have to open camera when the notification appears just like "sleep if you can" app

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sleep-if-u-can-alarm-forces/id609598558?mt=8

I am unable to analyze the app if it really does what it says because it is paid app.

My first concern is that it is feasible or not for iPhone, it works well with android. If it is feasible, how that can be achieved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "...because it is a paid app." It's not worth $1.99 to take a look?

Comment: any idea how does this app shows a notification "This app will not work if terminated" just right after it is being terminated. Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

When scheduling your local notification, add some information as the `userInfo` property of it.
Like so:

```
UILocalNotification *n = [UILocalNotification new];
n.alertBody = @"Some Alert Text. Take a picture!";
n.userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@YES, @"openCamera", nil];
n.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:n];
```

If your app is still running, when the user taps the Local Notification, the `application: didReceiveLocalNotification:` message will be sent to your AppDelegate. From there you can read out the userInfo:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if ([[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"openCamera"]  isEqual: @YES]) {
        // Do what is needed to open your camera
    }
}
```

If your app is not running, `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will be called. Inside this Method, you can read out the notification from the launching options and trigger your defined action like this:

```
UILocalNotification *n = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if (n) {
    [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:n];
}
```